# How does mysqli_query() know where to send the query if MySQL connection object doesn't contain information about the database server (password, etc)

Tags: php, mysql

I've output the MySQL connection object ($conn), and this is what is shown:

> mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 8.2.4
> [client_version] => 80204 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] =>
> [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0
> [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0
> [server_info] => 10.4.28-MariaDB [server_version] => 100428 [sqlstate]
> => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 402 [warning_count] => 0 )

No information about the server address, username, password, and database name.

How come when the connection object is passed, such as: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` it knows where to send the query?

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$dbname = "db1";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $dbname);

print_r($conn);

$sql = 'SELECT title FROM table1';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: It could be grabbing it from the php.ini. [`When passing null, the value is retrieved from mysqli.default_host.`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). Though. you're passing in `localhost`, so I would guess it's using that. It's not going to show sensitive information in the object. It's just going to create a link and store that.

Comment: @aynber none of the fields the OP mentions are being passed in as null

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, realized that after I made the first half of the comment.

Comment: Because `mysqli_connect` establishes a TCP connection, further commands are passed through the connection. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_connection_phase.html

Comment: `[host_info] => localhost` - that's the server address

Comment: Also, classes can define a magic method to hide information when dumping: https://3v4l.org/RJJfn

Comment: The PHP mysql connector calls the C API internally, and the connection is in there. The internal MySQL connector object doesn't have a PHP representation, so it's not  shown in `var_dump()`.